# Ansible ec2_facts outputs null

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, ansible

I am currently working on using Ansible for implementing rolling upgrade feature.

I was trying to gather ec2_facts using dynamic inventory however it outputs null and is not able to gather any information

command used:

```
 ansible localhost  -i ec2.py -m ec2_facts
```

OUTPUT

```
localhost | success >> {
"ansible_facts": {
    "ansible_ec2_public-key": null,
    "ansible_ec2_public_key": null,
    "ansible_ec2_user-data": null,
    "ansible_ec2_user_data": null
},
"changed": false
}
```

If I am trying it using

```
 ansible all  -i ec2.py -m ec2_facts
```

I recieve the following OUTPUT

```
No hosts matched
```

Can anyone point out what I am missing here ? Thanks

I have access keys set up correctly and I am able to get host information if I am doing

```
./ec2.py --list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by properly exporting aws credentials as mentioned here [Ansible AWS Guide](http://docs.ansible.com/guide_aws.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, but my issue was caused by proxies. So, my fix was to null out the proxy environment variables just for the ec2_facts.

```
- name: Gather EC2 facts
  local_action: ec2_facts
  environment:
    http_proxy: ""
    https_proxy: ""
```

Hope that helps future poor souls stuck with this issue